# Getting multiple picklist fields

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I'm using this wire adapter to fetch the six different picklist fields from the same object. is there a better way then repeating the same wire adapter code six times?

here is my code:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import INDUSTRY_FIELD1 from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Industry1';
import INDUSTRY_FIELD2 from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Industry2';
....

export default class Example extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '012000000000000AAA', fieldApiName: INDUSTRY_FIELD1 })
    picklist1;

   @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '012000000000000AAA', fieldApiName: INDUSTRY_FIELD2 })
    picklist2;

    .....
}
```

Comment: If you're using the OOTB wire services this is the way to do it. The alternative would be to write your own Apex to return all six lists of picklist values, but that feels like the wrong thing to do. I'd stick with what you have, personally. NB: This is really an opinion-based question, because really what is "better" here?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this sort of metadata is cached at the client-side once requested, and particularly because the fields you are working from are from the same object, once the first `@wire` (or other code that is fetching Account related metadata) has run, the next call will (probably) not involve any round trip to the server and so be close to instantaneous. So this simple coding pattern, rather than being wasteful, is actually a good way to go.

And the source code duplication looks harmless to me in this case, though do define a constant for the recordTypeId:

```
const RT_ID = '012000000000000AAA';

export default class Example extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getPicklistValues, {recordTypeId: RT_ID, fieldApiName: INDUSTRY_FIELD1})
    picklist1;
```

Comment: We can call more than a call for the same object and so, the second one will retrieve data. Once you're calling data for two different fields, you will need two calls, because Salesforce will make 2 API call to get picklist data even thought the fields belongs to the same object